# Is it better to use "faire une promenade" or "se promener"?

Tags: expressions, verbes

I know that both *faire une promenade* and *se promener* mean "to walk," but which one is considered better to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate with [this one](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3244/aller-faire-une-promenade-cest-quoi) ?

Comment: Quebec regionalism: "prendre une marche"

Answer (score 9):

If you say "je vais me promener" without saying where, you're going to wander, hang around.

But if you say "on va se promener en ville" ou bien "on a fait une promenade en forêt", you mean a real walk, enjoy the landscape, whatever.

Answer (score 7):

*Promenade/promener* do not quite equal "walk" (which would be the more generic *marcher*). They both imply a component of leisure, and are usually translated by "take a walk".

There is actually a nuance of meaning between *se promener* and *faire une promenade*, as the latter is a punctual action, but for the most part, both are grammatical. Personally I don't like *faire une/des promenade(s)* (I think it's clunky, especially in the plural), but it's probably just me.

Comment: I meant faire une promenade. I changed it.

Comment: punctual action?

Comment: It's a full, single time action with a specific beginning and end in the mind of the speaker. That's why only *promener* has the extended and metaphorical meanings along the lines of "wandering around".