# Aller faire une promenade, c'est quoi ?

Tags: usage, vocabulaire

Quelle est la différence entre *promenade* et *marcher* ?

Si ce sont deux expressions avec la même signification,
dans quelle situation on doit utiliser ces expressions et à quelle condition ?

Comment: merci beaucoup à vous tout les reponds sont vrai mais je ne peux pas accept tout, désolé!

Comment: Pas de problème, ce n'est pas une compétition ! Content d'avoir participé à t'aider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between "***faire une promenade***" and "***marcher***" is that "***faire une promenade***" emphasizes more on leisure and entertainment. Which means that with "***faire une promenade***", you'll take time to enjoy your walk, whereas with "***marcher***", you'd simply walk (including walking for exercising / relaxation).

For example, let's consider these 2 sentences:

> 1. "Je fais une promenade dans la forêt"
> 2. "Je marche dans la forêt"

The 2 sentences above mean "*`I'm walking in the forest`*", but the difference is that:

the 1st sentence means that you're walking in the forest **while taking time enjoying it**. For example, you may be enjoying the landscapes, discovering the forest, etc.

The 2nd sentence simply means that you're just simply walking through the forest, nothing special about it, **you're just passing by**. In this case, you may also be walking in the forest for doing some relaxation / sports.

---

La différence entre "***faire une promenade***" et "***marcher***" est que "***faire une promenade***" se focalise plus sur le fait de se divertir et de prendre du bon temps. On emploie "***faire une promenade***" pour une personne lorsque celle-ci prend son temps pour marcher et apprécier sa promenade, alors que l'on emploie "***marcher***" lorsque la personne marche tout simplement (ou pour faire de l'exercice, ou pour se relaxer).

Considérons les 2 phrases suivantes comme exemples:

> 1. "Je fais une promenade dans la forêt"
> 2. "Je marche dans la forêt"

Les 2 phrases ci-dessus signifient en anglais "*`I'm walking in the forest`*". Leur traduction est la même mais la différence est la suivante:

la 1ère phrase signifie que tu marches dans la forêt **tout en prenant du bon temps**. Par exemple, tu pourrais te promener pour admirer le paysage, ou pour découvrir les joies de la forêt, etc.

La 2ème phrase signifie simplement que tu marches normalement dans la forêt sans qu'il y ait quoique ce soit de spécial: **tu traverses tout simplement la forêt**. Dans le cas de cette 2ème phrase, tu pourrais aussi faire du sport ou de la relaxation.

Comment: Good answer. However, if you have a little spare time, maybe you should try to give an answer in the asker's tongue (maybe see [this](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/14/answering-in-the-other-language) also).

Comment: @RomainVALERI: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about it :O. I'll take your advice into account :). Thanks again.

Comment: Even though I don't think relying on translations to explain meanings is a good approach, I would have translated “je fais une promenade” by “I'm wandering”.

Answer (score 4):

Pour comparer des formes similaires, disons *se promener* et *marcher*.

**Marcher** est l'action de base, consistant techniquement à se déplacer à pied. Je vous épargne une description plus détaillée, je pense que tout le monde comprend de quoi il s'agit. C'est un verbe d'action générique et neutre, qui ne dit rien encore du contexte (promenade ? marche forcée ? autre ?).

**Se promener** (ou *faire une promenade*) consiste à se déplacer pour le plaisir des lieux traversés et de la légèreté de l'instant, non pas pour se rendre à un endroit spécifique. Et, souvent mais pas toujours, cela implique en effet de se déplacer en marchant.

Comment: On pourrait ajouter les synonymes : `excursion` : promenade touristique ; `ballade` (familier) flâner pour profiter d'un évènement, d'un lieu, d'un moment ; `randonnée` : longue promenade pouvant s'étaler sur plusieurs jours ; `vadrouille` : (familier) se promener pour trouver quelque chose : "les flics sont en vadrouille à la recherche de voleurs à la tire"

Comment: Dans certains coins de Lorraine, on entend aussi pas mal *(se) baguenauder* pour *se promener*...

Comment: @cl-r: L'orthographe correcte est "balade"; "ballade" existe mais a un sens différent.

Comment: @a3nm Exact, je me fais piéger à chaque fois : on peut se balader en chantant ou dansant des ballades : si on n'a pas le cœur en ballade, est-ce une vraie balade ? on reste alors sur une marche, c'est aussi autre tempo.